# Tags are converted to HTML entities?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse some dirty HTML. One such HTML is http://f10.5post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1142017

What happens is that, firstly, the tree misses a large chunk of the page. Secondly, `tostring(tree)` would convert tags like `<div>` on half of the page to HTML entities like `&lt;/div&gt;`. For instance

Original:

```
<div class="smallfont" align="centre">All times are GMT -4. The time now is <span class="time">02:12 PM</span>.</div>`
```

`toString(tree)` gives

```
&lt;div class="smallfont" align="center"&gt;All times are GMT -4. The time now is &lt;span class="time"&gt;02:12 PM&lt;/span&gt;.&lt;/div&gt;
```

Here's my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://f10.5post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1142017")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print soup
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and an *extremely lenient* `html5lib` [parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # NOTE: importing beautifulsoup4 here

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://f10.5post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1142017")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")

print soup
```

Comment: Do you know what the downside to using html5lib could be? Is it slower than the standard one?

Comment: @Kar different parsers parse HTML differently - in theory, you can get into situation where `html.parser` or `lxml` would produce a more accurate result than `html5lib`. Plus, `BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")` is usually the best option in terms of performance.